# How can I sync EXIF information when using a pre-saved PSD template?

Tags: raw, photoshop, metadata

I capture image in NEF format using Nikon D5100 and before posting on the net I make some changes, re-size it and move it on a pre-saved PSD file with water mark, nice border, ...
And after saving the image as JPG the EXIF tag shows wrong data, such as

- Canon Powershot A550, 5.5mm, f/7.1, ISO 200 [Yes, I have a A550 too]

**How can I solve the problem so the JPG shows same EXIF as the NEF** ?

Comment: With regard to your question: do you use the pre-saved PSD file as a template? I think what you want (a border and water mark) is easily achieved using Lightroom. In that way you preserve the EXIF info of the original NEF image.

Comment: I would also recommend learning to use photoshop actions so that you don't put it into this PSD file when editing inside of Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the problem here is that your saved PSD template has metadata associated with the file from which it was created — in this case, a file from your Canon powershot. When you paste the data from your converted NEF file on top of that, the metadata from *that* file isn't retained. (So, when you save/export, you get the original Canon information.)

One solution is to use a tool like exiv2 or ExifTool to copy the metadata from the NEF file to your final JPEG. Either one can do this fairly easily from the command line.